# .Net generate generic methods

Tags: c#, generics

I have a bunch of generic events I want to subscribe to and make them all call one non-generic method.  Here's my code:

```
public delegate void PropertyChangedDelegate<OwnerType, PropertyType>(OwnerType sender, PropertyType oldValue, PropertyType newValue);

public class EventObject
{
    public event PropertyChangedDelegate<Object, Boolean> PropertyChanged;
                public event PropertyChangedDelegate<Object, Int32> XChanged;
}

static void Main()
{
    EventObject eventObject = new EventObject();
    EventInfo eventInfo = eventObject.GetType().GetEvent("PropertyChanged");
    eventInfo.AddEventHandler(eventObject, PropertyChanged);
}

    static void PropertyChanged(Object obj, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
    {
    }
```

Obviously this doesn't work, is there any way to do a wrapper generic method?

Comment: Why are u using reflection here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `PropertyChanged` method is not contravariant to the `PropertyChangedDelegate` type because sending `bool` as `object` require boxing,  so it is clear that you cannot make delegate to work universally with all events. The solution is to write a static method as a "landing method". Here is my solution:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public delegate void PropertyChangedDelegate<OwnerType, PropertyType>(OwnerType sender, PropertyType oldValue, PropertyType newValue);

public class EventObject
{
    public event PropertyChangedDelegate<Object, Boolean> PropertyChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedDelegate<Object, Int32> XChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged() {
        PropertyChanged(this, true, false);
    }
}

class Test {

    static void Main()
    {
        EventObject eventObject = new EventObject();
        EventInfo eventInfo = eventObject.GetType().GetEvent("PropertyChanged"); 
        Type evType = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;
        // replace below with this.GetType() in case of instance method
        Type thisType = typeof(Test); 
        MethodInfo mi = thisType.GetMethod("PropertyChanged", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        MethodInfo genericMi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(evType.GetGenericArguments());
        Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(evType, genericMi);
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(eventObject, del);
        // Test
        eventObject.RaisePropertyChanged();
    }

    static void PropertyChanged<TOwner, T>(TOwner obj, T oldValue, T newValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-- Invoked --");
    }
}
```

Inspired from

[Using Reflection to get static method with its parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117372/using-reflection-to-get-static-method-with-its-)

and

[Create generic delegate using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419705/create-generic-delegate-using-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a method group as such in place of a delegate. You can specify the exact delegate your method matches to, like this:

```
EventObject eventObject = new EventObject();
EventInfo eventInfo = eventObject.GetType().GetEvent("PropertyChanged");
eventInfo.AddEventHandler(eventObject, (Action<Object, Object, Object>)PropertyChanged);
```

But it still would give you runtime exception since the signatures don't match.

Why not the straightforward `+=` implementation?

```
EventObject eventObject = new EventObject();
eventObject.PropertyChanged += PropertyChanged;
```

But this wont compile because of type mismatch in signature. You have to either change signature of delegate

```
public delegate void PropertyChangedDelegate(Object sender, Object oldValue, Object newValue);
```

or change signature of event

```
public event PropertyChangedDelegate<Object, Object> PropertyChanged;
```

(but that spoils all your efforts to have a strongly typed delegate) or change signature of method

```
static void PropertyChanged(Object obj, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue)
{
}
```

which is what I would go with.