# .NET generate generic method - compact framework

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Here is the original question where I'm looking for a way to generate a generic delegate:
[.Net generate generic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578867/net-generate-generic-methods/16579940#16579940)

Here is the code to generate a generic delegate in .NET 3.5:

```
public delegate void PropertyChangedDelegate<OwnerType, PropertyType>(OwnerType sender, String propertyName, PropertyType oldValue, PropertyType newValue);

EventInfo eventInfo = type.GetEvent(property.Name + "Changed");
MethodInfo propertyChangedMethodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("content_PropertyChanged", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
MethodInfo genericPropertyChangedMethodInfo = propertyChangedMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(eventInfo.EventHandlerType.GetGenericArguments());
Delegate delegate_ = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, genericPropertyChangedMethodInfo);
eventInfo.AddEventHandler(obj, delegate_);

void content_PropertyChanged<OwnerType, PropertyType>(OwnerType sender, String propertyName, PropertyType oldValue, PropertyType newValue)
{
}
```

This works in .NET 3.5, but now when I tried to port to the compact framework 3.5, the Delegate.CreateDelegate method requires a third parameter...  The parameter description says:

> it should be the first argument, or 'the object to which the delegate
>   is bound'.

I tried putting 'obj' in there, and 'this', and null, and I always get an invalid argument exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that there is something wrong with the other two arguments on the compact platform?

Comment: I tried the exact same thing with three arguments like this on the desktop .NET and it worked: Delegate delegate_ = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this, genericPropertyChangedMethodInfo);

Comment: I looked closer and the error said: "ReturnType for Open Generic methods is not supported"... hmmm

Comment: I think this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148849/why-cant-i-call-delegate-createdelegate-in-my-portable-class-library

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately .NETCF (.NET Compact Framework) doesn't support the same method signatures as .NET (full framework) as only a subset is implemented.

You can see this on the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) where only one of the ten method overloads is "Supported by the .NET Compact Framework", indicated with the small graphic of a PDA/mobile.

[image: CreateDelegate method]

This means you **have** to use [Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type, Object, MethodInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in .NETCF.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the example section in the link below and see if it helps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551.aspx

Regards,

Zahir Khan