# Why can't I call Delegate.CreateDelegate in my Portable Class Library?

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I have the following problem: I want to call `Delegate.CreateDelegate` from within my Portable Class Library targeting .NET 4.5, Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 Store Apps, but my code does not compile. The compiler says that it cannot find the method on the `Delegate` type.

The funny thing is that e.g. the PRISM library by Microsoft can call 'Delegate.CreateDelegate' from a Portable Class Library. It does so in the `DelegateReference` class. The PRISM portable class library targets .NET 4.0, Windows 8 Store Apps, Windows Phone 8 and Silverlight 5 (and thusly an even more restrictive set).

The code that does not compile looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod<T>(EventHandler handler)
    {
        var @delegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (OpenEventHandler<T>), null, handler.GetMethodInfo());
    }
}

public delegate void OpenEventHandler<in T>(T target, object sender, EventArgs arguments);
```

An example can be downloaded here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14810011/PortableClassLibraryReferenceProblem.zip

It contains my library project and a very stripped version of the PRISM PubSubEvents project containing only the `DelegateReference` class and its interface. The complete source code of the latter can be found here: http://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

What can I do to use all `Delegate` members? Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT** after Henk Holterman's answer:

GetMethodInfo() is an extension method that is supported by the PCL subset. Anyway, that is not related to the problem that I cannot call `Delegate.CreateDelegate` while PRISM's PCL project can.

[image: Picture of code that does not compile]

**EDIT 2** after Hans Passants comment:

I just played around and found out that when I activate Silverlight 5 as a target of the portable library then `Delegate.CreateDelegate` is indeed accessible (and the GetMethodInfo Extension Method no longer is). Is `Delegate.CreateDelegate` then maybe mapped to another API for Windows 8 Store and Phone apps internally? It's the only way I could think of how this method would be suddenly accessible just because I added Silverlight 5 as a valid target.

(You can reproduce this by right-clicking on the "MyPortableClassLibrary" project, click "Properties" and in the "Library" tab click change to select the frameworks that are targeted by the portable library.)

Also, earlier today, I created an Windows Store App project and saw that there was no `CreateDelegate` method defined on the `Delegate` class in .NET for Windows Runtime.

In my actual project, I do not want to target Silverlight 5 as I use `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>` heavily using Rx and these interfaces are not defined in Silverlight.

Comment: Works just fine on my machine.

Comment: @Hans I recognize you did not download the sample code? Because it's not working there. Anyway, I updated my question to my recent findings.

Comment: This is a problem with portable libraries, some subsets give different APIs, it happened me with some reflection types that were not available on Windows 8/Phone subsets until I targeted Silverlight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are seeing when you add/remove Silverlight, is portable flipping between two different .NET API surface areas. I cover these two different surface areas here: [What is .NET Portable Subset (Legacy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483951/what-is-net-portable-subset-legacy/12538648#12538648).

In what we call the legacy surface area, this method lives on Delegate. 
In the new surface area, this method has been moved to MethodInfo.

*Why did we do this?*

For layering reasons. In the new surface, reflection types (ie Assembly, MemberInfo, MethodInfo, etc) are considered as living in a higher layer than the core primitives, which includes Delegate. Unlike the legacy surface area (where they all live in mscorlib), these types in different assemblies; System.Reflection.dll and System.Runtime.dll, respectively.

This method (a few others) were causing something at a lower layer (System.Runtime.dll) to depend on something at a higher layer (System.Reflection.dll). To prevent that, the dependency was reversed.

Comment: Thank you for the additional insights, David.

Answer (score 13):

OK, after a night of sleeping I recognized that my question actually should be **"How do I dynamically create delegates in the new API introduced with the Windows Runtime?"**. As Rafael indicated in the comments of my question, different APIs are provided when Windows 8 / Phone 8 is targeted in addition to .NET. If Silverlight is also targeted, then APIs that are not available in Windows 8 / Phone 8 will be mapped and this explains why I can suddenly call `Delegate.CreateDelegate` when I add Silverlight as a target of the Portable Class Library. In .NET, the new APIs for Reflection were introduced with .NET 4.5.

Anyway, to create a delegate in Windows 8 / Windows Phone 8, one has to use the `MethodInfo.CreateDelegate` method, just like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod<T>(EventHandler handler)
    {
        var methodInfo = handler.GetMethodInfo();
        var @delegate = methodInfo.CreateDelegate(typeof(OpenEventHandler<T>), null);
    }
}

public delegate void OpenEventHandler<in T>(T target, object sender, EventArgs arguments);
```