# Portable Class Library Reflection GetField

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, portable-class-library

I am currently trying to convert a Xamarin.iOS app library to a PCL. I have this code that will not compile:

```
    private void SetPrivateField<T>(object item, string fieldName, object value) {
        typeof(T).GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .SetValue(item, value);
    }
```

As you can see I am trying to set a private field for a type. Is there another way?

**EDIT**
This compiles. Will it do the same thing?

```
 private void SetPrivateField<T>(object item, string fieldName, object value) {
      typeof(T).GetRuntimeField(fieldName).SetValue(item,value);
 }
```

Comment: What's the *compiler?* error being reported ?

Comment: @poupou The name 'BindingFlags' does not exist in the current context (im compiling in visual studio)

Comment: What profile are you using ? there are major difference in the reflection api exposed in 78 and 158

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix I am using profile 78. See edits above.

Comment: @ChrisKooken Did you find out how to dynamically access an inherited property in PCL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ended up being the correct code.

```
private void SetPrivateField<T>(object item, string fieldName, object value) {
    typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredField(fieldName).SetValue(item,value);
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. For better performance, it is usually better to cache the setters.

Answer (score 2):

The reflection APIs in Portable Class Libraries targeting newer platforms are different.  See the following links for some info on why we did this and how to use the new APIs:

- [Portable Class library and reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061291/portable-class-library-and-reflection/14063316#14063316)
- [Why can't I call Delegate.CreateDelegate in my Portable Class Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148849/why-cant-i-call-delegate-createdelegate-in-my-portable-class-library/18242176#18242176)
- Blog post: [Evolving the Reflection API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx)